# How To Programmatically Cause the Creation of a User's Profile

Tags: c#, c++, windows, account, winapi

How To Programmatically Create a User's Profile from the NetworkServices account at
WinServer 2008 r2.

THX, Alex

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what are restrictions to `NetworkServices` account, but to create new user you can use [`New-ADUser`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee617253.aspx) Cmdlet.

Example how to use Cmdlets from C#: ["Call PowerShell Cmdlets from C#"](http://www.devx.com/tips/Tip/42716)

Comment: Is it possible to add user in Workgroup, not domain.